# AND operator in case statement

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, case

I have following code.

```
read -p "Enter a word: " word

case $word in
  [aeiou]* | [AEIOU]*)
          echo "The word begins with a vowel." ;;
  [0-9]*)
          echo "The word begins with a digit." ;;
  *[0-9])
          echo "The word ends with a digit." ;;
  [aeiou]* && [AEIOU]* && *[0-9])
          echo "The word begins with vowel and ends with a digit." ;;
   ????)
          echo "You entered a four letter word." ;;
   *)
          echo "I don't know what you've entered," ;;
esac
```

When I run this:

```
Enter a word: apple123
case2.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'
case2.sh: line 10: `  [aeiou]* && [AEIOU]* && *[0-9])'
```

It looks like case statement don't support AND operator, and also I believe the && operator in my above case statement logically incorrect.

I understand that we can use if else to check if the input starts with a vowel and digit. But I am curious if case has any inbuilt function like AND operator.

Comment: Use `|` instead of `&&`. Have in mind that the conditions are mutually exclusive: it is OR not AND.

Comment: @guillermochamorro My end goal is if the user enters input that starts with vowel and ends with a number, it needs to print "The word ends with vowel AND ends with a digit.". But if I use OR (|), it will be escaped and I guess the case statement will choose option [aeiou]* | [AEIOU]* instead.

Comment: @smc I suppose [aeiouAEIOU]*[0-9] would cover that case, but you'd need to have that as the first case because otherwise it would be covered by the current first one. Besides, your logic for begins/ends is wrong in a few places.

Comment: @DonHolgo Ah, thanks for the hint. It worked, I also modified my question where my logic was wrong. Please feel free to make this comment as answer :).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct in that the [standard definition of `case`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_05) does not allow for a AND operator in the pattern. You're also correct that trying to say "starts with a lower-case vowel AND starts with an upper-case vowel" would not match anything. Note also that you have your patterns & explanations reversed for the begins/ends with a digit tests -- using a pattern of `[0-9]*` would match words that *begin* with a digit, not *end* with a digit.

One approach this would be to combine your tests into the same pattern, most-restrictive first:

```
case $word in
  ([AaEeIiOoUu]??[0-9]) echo it is four characters long and begins with a vowel and ends with a digit;;
  ([AaEeIiOoUu]*[0-9])  echo it is not four characters long begins with a vowel and ends with a digit;;
# ...
esac
```

Another (lengthy!) approach would be to nest your `case` statements, building up appropriate responses each time. Does it begin with a vowel, yes or no? Now, does it end in a digit, yes or no? This would get unwieldy quickly, and annoying to maintain.

Another approach would be to use a sequence of `case` statements that builds up a string (or array) of applicable statements; you could even add `*` catch-all patterns to each if you wanted to provide "negative" feedback ("word does *not* begin with a vowel", etc).

```
result=""
case $word in
  [AaEeIiOoUu]*)
          result="The word begins with a vowel." ;;
esac

case $word in
  [0-9]*)
          result="${result} The word begins with a digit." ;;
esac

case $word in
  *[0-9])
          result="${result} The word ends with a digit." ;;
esac

case $word in
   ????)
          result="${result} You entered four characters." ;;
esac

printf '%s\n' "$result"
```

For examples:

```
$ ./go.sh
Enter a word: aieee
The word begins with a vowel.
$ ./go.sh
Enter a word: jeff42
 The word ends with a digit.
$ ./go.sh
Enter a word: aiee
The word begins with a vowel. You entered four characters.
$ ./go.sh
Enter a word: 9arm
 The word begins with a digit. You entered four characters.
$ ./go.sh
Enter a word: arm9
The word begins with a vowel. The word ends with a digit. You entered four characters.
```

Alternatively, [bash extended the syntax for the `case` statement](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs) to allow for multiple patterns to be selected, if you end the pattern(s) with `;;&`:

```
shopt -s nocasematch
case $word in
  [aeiou]*)
          echo "The word begins with a vowel." ;;&
  [0-9]*)
          echo "The word begins with a digit." ;;&
  *[0-9])
          echo "The word ends with a digit." ;;&
   ????)
          echo "You entered four characters." ;;
esac
```

Note that I removed the `*` catch-all pattern, since that would match anything & everything, when falling through the patterns this way. Bash also has a shell option called `nocasematch`, which I set above, that enables case-insensitive matching of the patterns. That helps reduce redundancy -- I removed the `| [AEIOU]*` part of the pattern.

For examples:

```
$ ./go.sh
Enter a word: aieee
The word begins with a vowel.
$ ./go.sh
Enter a word: jeff42
The word ends with a digit.
$ ./go.sh
Enter a word: aiee
The word begins with a vowel.
You entered four characters.
$ ./go.sh
Enter a word: 9arm
The word begins with a digit.
You entered four characters.
$ ./go.sh
Enter a word: arm9
The word begins with a vowel.
The word ends with a digit.
You entered four characters.
```

Comment: I was preparing a similar answer using `;;&` but i was late! +1 for the nice answer :-) You can also fake a kind of `and` using something like `[0-9]*);;&*[0-9]) echo "word begins and ends with number";;`

Comment: Thanks @jeff-schaller for the explanation, also I have corrected my question after George pointed out about the incorrect placement of "words begins/ends with" part.

Comment: Note that `zsh` had `;|` (also supported by mksh) before (2007) bash added `;;&` (2009) for the same thing (`;&` itself comes from ksh88e, added to zsh in 1997 and bash in 2009).

Comment: For booleans (0 or 1) `A` and `B`, the usual solution is `case $A$B in 11) .... `. Simpler.

Answer (score 6):

For completeness, while `case` has a `|` OR operator, it doesn't have an AND operator but if using shells with extended glob operators (ksh, zsh, bash), you can implement the AND in the **pattern** syntax:

- `ksh93`'s `@(x&y&z)` operator:

  ```
    case $string in
      ( @({12}(?)&~(i:[aeiou]*)&*[0123456789]) )
        echo is 12 characters long AND starts with a vowel AND ends in a decimal
    esac
  ```
- `zsh` (using `~` (AND-NOT) combined with `^` (NOT)): `x~^y~^z`

  ```
    set -o extendedglob
    case $string in
      ( ?(#c12)~^(#i)[aeiou]*~^*[0-9] )
        echo is 12 characters long AND starts with a vowel AND ends in a decimal
    esac
  ```
- `ksh88`, `bash`, using double negation with OR (`!(!(x)|!(y)|!(z))`)

  ```
    shopt -s extglob # bash only
    case $string in
      ( !(!(????????????)|!([aAeEıiIİoOuU]*)|!(*[0123456789])) )
        echo is 12 characters long AND starts with a vowel AND ends in a decimal
    esac
  ```

In any case, remember that except in zsh where ranges are always based on codepoint values, ranges like `[0-9]` cannot be used reliably outside of the POSIX/C locale (hence the `[0123456789]` instead above).

ksh93 and zsh's case insensitive matching operators (`~(i)` and `(#i)`) honour the locale for case sensitive comparison. For instance, in a Turkish locale on a GNU system, `(#i)[aeiou]` will match on `İ`, but not `I` (because uppercase `i` is `İ` there). To get a consistent outcome regardless of the locale, you may want to hard code all possible values instead like in the ksh88/bash approach.

Comment: For booleans (0 or 1) `A` and `B`, the usual solution is `case $A$B in 11) ...`. Simpler.

Answer (score 3):

The usual **portable** solution to implement an AND in case statements is to concatenate the boolean values:

```
case $A$B in
    11) echo "Both conditions are true";;
    1*) echo "Condition A is true";;
    *1) echo "Condition B is true";;
    00) echo "Both conditions are false";;
     *) echo "There is an unexpected error";;
esac
```

For your use case:

```
printf "Enter a word: "; read word

A=0 B=0 C=0

case $word in    ( [aeiouAEIOU]* ) A=1;; esac
case $word in    ( *[0-9]        ) B=1;; esac
case $word in    ( ????          ) C=1;; esac

case $A$B$C in
  111)     echo "Four letters that start with a vowel and end with a digit" ;;
  11*)     echo "The word begins with a vowel AND ends with a digit."       ;;
  1* )     echo "The word begins with a vowel."                             ;;
  *1?)     echo "The word ends with a digit."                               ;;
   *1)     echo "The word is four letters long"                             ;;
    *)     echo "I don't understand what you've entered,"                   ;;
esac
```

Using a portable case for each boolean option. You can use `;;&` in bash, or `;|` in zsh. Sadly ksh doesn't have such option for case.

An alternative to set the booleans (in some shells: ksh, bash, zsh at least) is:

```
[[ $word ==   [aeiouAEIOU]* ]] && A=1 || A=0
[[ $word ==   *[0-9]        ]] && B=1 || B=0
[[ $word ==   ????          ]] && C=1 || c=0
```